# Can we have an exception to the moderator election to address a popular tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, moderator-election

Currently a moderator election is going on. Of course whoever has got the most upvotes will be selected without any doubt.

We have the [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) tag which has the most questions asked on a daily basis, which need to be moderated daily. It is bad that no Android-experienced candidates made it to the top 3. For the record, I [checked on data.stackexchange.com](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/301114/most-popular-stackoverflow-tags-until-may-2014) and I found that [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) got 4th position in the list of most popular tags.

Is it possible to get a candidate elected on the basis of Android experience? Pick the person who has got the most upvotes of all Android-experienced candidates. I know that's not in our community's rules. But we can have an **exception** if it is for the good of the community.

Comment: A moderators job doesn't involve checking the technical accuracy of posts.

Comment: Joe W is correct. If you feel like not enough 10K users are handling community moderation issues; flag it for us, but your hit rate will depend on how busy we are otherwise (so you may receive declinations for what you thought were viable flags).  It's an imperfect solution, but it's all I've got.

Comment: Any moderation that requires expert Android knowledge should already be taken care of *by the community*. Vote, vote to close, comment, etc. Community moderators handle the exceptional cases, *outside* of the technical focus of posts.

Comment: It would be nice if reputation barriers for actions in a certain tag was dependent upon reputation in that tag; that way 3K users in Android could act as 10K users if there weren't enough 10K users to fill that gap (it also works for nascent tags, where there isn't a lot of experience yet).

Comment: You might be asking for more users in the [android] community to be actively involved.  Yes, that's a problem, they barely even vote for posts.  Hard to fix.

Comment: Sorry, I knew already that can not be possible anyway also I have less knowledge about moderators tools. That was just what I thought and shared. :-) .

Comment: If you see a poor question that doesn't show research, is unclear, or not useful - down vote it (this is one of the primary tools you have for sorting quality). If there is a question that is lacking the code to reproduce the question, close vote it. By voting on questions you help others see what is worth while to spend their time on. By close voting questions you help the user understand what needs to be fixed and help keep the long tail clean.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The first thing I should say is that primary voting does not necessarily reflect the final election results. I came in third in one primary, only to be at the bottom in the final election. Don't take those numbers as foregone conclusions. The final election uses a different voting scheme.

Beyond that, moderators have to handle issues in every tag. Despite me being a Mac and iOS developer, I bet I've handled issues on far more Android or Windows development questions than anything else. For example, the Android tag used to have a terrible problem with sock puppets and voting rings, so I and other moderators focused our efforts on tearing those down. That required no technical knowledge of Android to deal with.

That said, there are cases where it can help to have someone in the moderation team with experience in a certain area. People complain about duplicates all the time (whether something should be closed as a duplicate or they think it was closed incorrectly), and that can require us to examine two questions in detail to determine if the subject matter is the same. I'll often defer to people with experience on those.

Also, sometimes a question that others think is unsalvageable can be edited into shape by someone with knowledge of the source material. Likewise with things flagged as non-answers, where it may just be a matter of better phrasing required.

A larger concern for us is availability of moderators. We're very heavy on moderators operating during U.S. business hours. This leaves us light during Indian business hours, when unfortunately we see some of our highest  rates of spam or troubling content coming in. It would be nice to have more moderators who could service that time of day so we are able to respond promptly to things then.

Still, you shouldn't just pick someone based on time zone or area of expertise. Being level-headed and fully understanding the responsibilities of a moderator should be more important, but it's up to you to weigh all of these factors when deciding who to vote for.