# Does the current election process suits the community needs?

Tags: discussion, moderators, moderator-election

It's the final day of election, and I decided to cast my vote(s).

So I browsed to each of the candidate's profiles.

With huge respect for everybody offering themselves to be moderators, and the contribution they will bring to the community, I've noticed what might be a (probably minor) problem :

The main criteria for candidate score are it's contribution to the community (which ofc is normal ). However answers / questions provide the same amount of reputation and badges, regardless of language (and ofc, this is normal, you cannot discriminate a developer based on his/her's religion ;) ).

However the moderators have some responsibilities that demand some know-how of a programming language (such as protecting / locking questions).

Q : Shouldn't moderators be also selected keeping the need of moderator language-specific know-how ?

Fictional Example :
This year, due to the sudden increase in Cobol questions, SO added an extra moderator seat to allow the finding of a moderator with Cobol experience.

In the current final moderators pool, all the moderators have a common pool of knowledge (with two exceptions). I cannot find any moderator (in the current election pool) which knows my the development language I'm interested in.

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the responsibilities of a moderator, but I would feel much more confident if I would know that moderators have themselves the appropriate knowledge to take actions on some specific posts , without entirely relying on flags and reports.

To be clear, I don't enforce discriminating developers by the language they are working in (we are all engineers in the end), I'm just questioning if SO community wold benefit from having at least 1 moderator / major tag (be it programming language, library, operating system etc).

Comment: *"the moderators have some responsibilities that demand some know-how of a programming language"* - I don't think that this is true. It's not the job of a moderator to provide technical input, but to ensure that site rules are being adhered to.

Comment: Why does protecting/locking questions require domain knowledge?

Comment: Moderating definitely does not require know-how of a programming language.

Comment: My response to a similar question: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290442/can-we-have-an-exception-to-the-moderator-election-to-address-a-popular-tag/290456#290456

Comment: Modraters are not only monkeys with guns in there hands but are also (and primarily) janitors.  You don't need a PhD in math to mop up vomit in a classroom.  You need a mop.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Moderators do not require subject domain knowledge in order to moderate.

There are only a few exceptions.  Closing as duplicate does require *some* domain knowledge.  That's why we give gold badge holders a [magic hammer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dupehammer).  But that has more to do with being a software developer than it does having the specific knowledge that the question entails.  If a developer not well-versed in a technology cannot tell if two questions are duplicate or not, they're probably not similar enough to be judged as duplicates by someone outside the domain.

Protecting a question doesn't require domain knowledge at all.  All it requires is the ability to tell when people are bikeshedding and spamming a question.

Comment: "Closing as duplicate does require some domain knowledge." In addition to that, improving the questions of a particular domain, say for example, Android!

Comment: That's not one of the duties of a moderator.  A moderator can certainly participate as a community member, but it's not the same thing.

Comment: Yeah I know that's not the duty of a moderator but here is where moderator can be involved, who has domain knowledge of that particular area!

Comment: @PareshMayani but that's independent of their moderation duties (assuming them have any time left over!) and therefore not relevant to the question in terms of mod elections.

Comment: Well, if you guys never felt the need of domain specific know-how , then I guess everything is fine :) .